# Is landlord entitled to show residential rental property to prospective buyers?

Tags: england-and-wales, landlord, tenancy-rules

Alice rents a house from Bob and she lives there. Bob wishes to sell the house and gets serial interested prospective buyers, none of whose offers he wishes to accept. As a result he basically arranges successive viewings with these different new buyers every week, and gives Alice 72 hours notice before each one.

Must she tolerate these weekly disturbances to her home, or may she insist that Bob wait until her tenancy concludes to show the house any more?

Comment: See: https://landlordlawblog.co.uk/2022/01/17/tenant-asks-if-he-is-allowed-to-refuse-access-to-his-landlord-for-new-tenant-viewings/